# Solution file gets changed with Visual Studio update, should I check in?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, sln-file

Recently my system got update and with that visual studio also gets updated. It looks like minor update. Now my project solution file contains Visual Studio version which is changed now. Should I check in the Solution file? Will it affect project configuration setting?

Answer (score 0):

If the version of the solution file has changed, the solution was probably created with an earlier version of visual studio than 2012. (I am assuming that based on the tags attached to the question). upgrades to a solution file will prevent earlier versions of visual studio from using the project.

If that is a project requirement do not update the solution file and use the same version of visual studio that the rest of the team is using. If this is not an issue, check the file in.